# Scroll from source keymap / go to file / locate file in project view

Tags: android-studio

I've searched throu lots of articles but not found an answer, some has come up with workarounds but not really answered the question.

**I want to locate a file in the project view over the files in [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html).**

There is in the project view a button named scroll from source, this one does what I want. But I want it as a keyboard shortcut, like the command in [Visual Studio](http://www.visualstudio.com/) many has as shift alt l. The [resharper command](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Keyboard_Shortcuts.html) is [locate in solution explorer](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Locating_a_File_in_Solution_Explorer.html)

There is also an option in the project view to mark always scroll from source.

These options are useful but do not solve my question.

One might think this would do it, but I don't want the project view over the files to scroll up and down all the time. I want a keyboard short cut because that is what feels fastest to me to work with and makes it more comfortable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's possible to achieve this by typing `Alt + F1` followed by `Enter`. If you want to change that to one button press then your best bet is to record those commands as a macro.

To do this go to `Edit > Macros > Start Macro Recording`. Then press `Alt + F1` followed by `Enter`. Then go to `Edit > Macros > Stop Macro Recording` and give your macro a name when prompted. Now that your macro is saved you can assign a key binding to it. Go into `Settings > IDE Settings > Keymap > Macros` and there you will find your macro which you can then bind.

It didn't seem to work for me unless it was a single keypress so I bound the macro to `F10`.

Comment: Works for PHPStorm too!